# Why does the inversion of the unit circle centered at $-i$ give the horizontal line $y = \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: mobius-transformation, mobius-inversion

Inverting the circle centered at $-i$ with radius $1$, gives the horizontal line $y = \frac{1}{2}$, but why does the line have to be horizontal? Why not another straight line passing through the imaginary axis at $\frac{i}{2}$?

I understand that inverting the point on this circle that is furthest from the origin, namely $-2i$, gives the point on the image closest to the origin in the $w$-plane, namely $-\frac{1}{2i} = \frac{i}{2}$.  But the notes that I am reading conclude at this point that the line must be horizontal.

Comment: Symmetry of the circle with respect to the y-axis. (Unrelated: the line is y=1/2, not y=i/2.)

Comment: Ah, of course.  Thanks @Did!  Nice profile summary, btw.  I hope you win your battles against the administration - I am guessing it is academia politics :-)

Comment: Well, thanks for the wish, it is most appreciated. (You know the story about these, most of the time you lose, sometimes you kind of win, but in the mean time you meet people and some of them can even become true friends...)

Answer (score 1):

Inversion preserves angles. The imaginary axis is preserved by inversion, and the imaginary axis intersects the circle perpendicularly at $-2i$. Thus, the inverse of the circle must intersect the imaginary axis perpendicularly at $\frac i2$. Thus, the line must be perpendicular to the imaginary axis; that is, horizontal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also compute the inversion explicitly.  Suppose $z$ is a point on the desired circle; then $|z+i|=1$, whence $z+i=e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta$, and therefore $z=e^{i\theta}-i$.

Now the inversion of this is $z=\frac{1}{e^{i\theta}-i}=\frac{1}{\cos\theta + i(\sin\theta-1)}=\frac{\cos\theta - i(\sin\theta-1)}{\cos^2\theta+(\sin\theta-1)^2}=\frac{\cos\theta - i(\sin\theta-1)}{2-2\sin\theta}=\frac{\cos\theta}{2-2\sin\theta}-i\frac{\sin\theta-1}{2-2\sin\theta}=\frac{\cos\theta}{2-2\sin\theta}+\frac{i}{2}$

and you can see that as $\theta$ varies, the imaginary part is always $i/2$.